# Fill records in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with "n" number of records. Within that table there is a field called User.

| Records | User |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 |  |
| 0002 |  |
| 0003 |  |
| 0004 |  |
| 0005 |  |
| 0006 |  |
| 0007 |  |

The administrator selected certain users that are stored in another table called Selected Users

| Selected User |
| --- |
| Tom |
| Mike |
| Nick |

How can I distribute the records among the selected users? I fill the User field with the name of the Selected Users, updating the table in this way:

| Records | User |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Tom |
| 0002 | Mike |
| 0003 | Nick |
| 0004 | Tom |
| 0005 | Mike |
| 0006 | Nick |
| 0007 | Tom |

I have tried autofill using a query but it assigns me the names of the selected analysts for each record, which means excessively increasing the records for each selected analyst.

I have experimented with a for loop but I can't find where to enter the query

```
Dim i As Byte
For i = 1 To product
    DoCmd.RunSQL ""
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Autonumber field (1, 2, 3) to `Selected Users`, and you can run a *Cartesian* query:

```sql
SELECT 
    User.Records, 
    [Selected Users].[Selected User]
FROM 
    [User], 
    [Selected Users]
WHERE 
    1 + (2 + Val([Records])) Mod 3 = [Id];
```

[image]